# Coordinates/Region from Country Name

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mapkit, core-location

How can I extract a `CLRegion` or `CLLocationCoordinate2D` or latitude/longitude points based on a correctly written country name? Would `CLGeocoder` work like this:

```
 CLGeocoder *geoCode = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geoCode geocodeAddressString:@"Singapore" completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks,       NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
      CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%i,%i", place.//what would i put here);

}


   }];
```

What variable does a `CLPlacemark` hold that tells the address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never mind figured it out:

```
  CLGeocoder *geoCode = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geoCode geocodeAddressString:@"Singapore" completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocation *location = place.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = location.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"%g is latitude and %g is longtitude", coord.latitude, coord.longitude);

    }


}];
```